# (leave) Till/to/for

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, prepositions

Which one is correct, and which one sounds more natural?

1. Leave that to tomorrow/later/another day/last minute
2. Leave that for tomorrow/later/another day/last minute
3. Leave that till tomorrow/later/another day/last minute

I looked up ”leave it” and, according to Cambridge dictionary, the preposition ”till” should be used. However, I later searched it up to be sure, and some people say ”use till” ”never use to or for” ”you can use all of them.” This really left me more confused. I think I’ve always used ”for” and sometimes ”till” but I wanna be sure of which preposition should be used.

Comment: All three are usages I use/have heard often.  I'd also sometimes say *until* instead of *til(l)*

Comment: They have slightly different connotations.

Comment: [Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leave+it+to+tomorrow%2Cleave+it+till+tomorrow%2Cleave+it+until+tomorrow%2Cleave+it+for+tomorrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleave%20it%20till%20tomorrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleave%20it%20until%20tomorrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleave%20it%20for%20tomorrow%3B%2Cc0) show that 'until', 'till' and 'for' are reasonably common before 'tomorrow'.